# Infer struct structure

Tags: go

I am using this to create a struct without defining a separate type:

```
data := struct {
    Product *domain.UserProduct
    Options *[]domain.UserProductOption
}{
    Product: userProduct,
    Options: userProductOptions,
}
```

Is there a way to do the same without defining `struct`'s structure, as number of fields and their types can inferred? Something like:

```
data := {
    Product: userProduct,
    Options: userProductOptions,
}
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to do the same without defining struct's structure"* -- Nope, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

As of Go 1.17 there's nothing like that to infer the type of a struct.

There's been some discussion of this in the proposal [#35304](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35304#issuecomment-559452397), but it's still open. To summarize the discussion:

- `foo({x: y})` - unreadable
- `data := _{x: y}` - unreadable (?)
- `data := struct {x: y}` - overloads the syntax of `struct`
- `data := tuple {x: y}` - new keyword
- . . .

You're welcome to participate in the discussion and/or submit your own proposal.

I would think something like `data := struct _ {X: x, Y: y}` should be the most in line with the philosophy of `_` being used to omit things (as in this case we want to omit the struct definition).

Comment: very interesting, too bad the discussion seems kinda stuck. Personally I like the syntax `struct{...}{x: 1, y: 2}`, which has resemblance with the array literal `[...]int{1,2,3}`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do the same without defining struct's structure

No. The language doesn't allow it: in [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), it is defined how these work:

> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. **They consist of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.** Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.

```
CompositeLit  = LiteralType LiteralValue .

LiteralType   = StructType | ArrayType | "[" "..." "]" ElementType |
                SliceType | MapType | TypeName .

LiteralValue  = "{" [ ElementList [ "," ] ] "}" .
```

The place where you can have the literal value is in an element list:

```
// the struct type may be defined or literal

// defined type
type User struct {
   Name string
}

// `{"John"}` is the literal value
foo := []User{{"John"}}

// literal type
// `{"John","john@myself.com"}` is the literal value
bar := []struct{Name string; Email string}{{"John","john@myself.com"}}
```